# Cloning a repository in umbraco as a service doesn't download the website

Tags: git, cloud, umbraco

I'm working with a project in Umbraco as a service. it offers the possibility to clone a Git repository to your local machine.

[Umbraco as a service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDlRT.jpg)

However, when I clone the repository using Git Extensions, the content of the website (media library, data types, actual pages, etc) is not downloaded. If I set up a website using IIS pointing to the umbraco folder I can access the platform but when I click on restore site it shows a "connecting... 0 of 0" message.

[Restore site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzyqi.jpg)

Any idea of what can it be?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem with authentication to Umbraco as a Service, can you check please your credentials, process of downloading is right.